# how to send and receive file in JSON between android and node js

Tags: android, json, node.js, sockets, express

i want to send files in JSON to an express node js server using socket, i don't know how to do it , i started with the android code , but i don't know how to get it in the server side. here is the android code :

```
    package fr.learning_adventure.android.itac.model;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.Serializable;

// Created by Moez on 02/03/16.


public class Learner implements Serializable{

    private final static String JSON_PSEUDO = "pseudo";

    private final static String JSON_MAC = "mac";



    private String pseudo;




    private String mac;

    public Learner(String mac, String pseudo) {
        this.pseudo = pseudo;
        this.mac = mac;

    }


    public Learner(JSONObject object) {
        try {
            this.pseudo = object.getString(Learner.JSON_PSEUDO);
            this.mac = null;

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public String getPseudo() {
        return this.pseudo;
    }

    public void setPseudo(String pseudo) {
        this.pseudo = pseudo;
    }

    public JSONObject toJSON() {
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
        try {
            object.putOpt(Learner.JSON_PSEUDO,this.pseudo);
            object.putOpt(Learner.JSON_MAC, this.mac);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return object;
    }


}
```

Comment: Your question is too wide..

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a DTO class containing information to send and then when you are about to send the object via socket call :

```
new Gson().toJson(DTO);
```

[What is Data Transfer Object DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object)

[Gson user guide](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md)